# Count status Id for each day

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Situation:**

I have three tables. Table 1 has Ids and subscribed date. Table 2 has Ids, activity status and the most recent date of the activity status change.
Table 3 has Ids and all the logs for status changes.
**Note:** *On the Subscribed date, all IDs are active. When there are more than one status change in one day, the most recent one is the one to choose.*

**Objective:**

I need to figure out the # of IDs for each status on each day. I.e. How many people were active, inactive and risky every single day.
My issue is making sure that the status of an ID is counted everyday even if there are no data on a specific day. For example:
ID 1 (see fiddle below) has been active since May 2nd (joindate) and had no status change, so he should be counted as active every single day until now.

After consulting this problem elsewhere, some have proposed to create function and a cross apply and store the counts in a table. I do not have the skills to do so but would that be an option to solve this issue?

**Desired Output:**

```
+------------+----------+-------+
|    date    |  status  | count |
+------------+----------+-------+
| 1-May-2019 | active   |     0 |
| 1-May-2019 | inactive |     0 |
| 1-May-2019 | risky    |     1 |
| 2-May-2019 | active   |     1 |
| 2-May-2019 | inactive |     0 |
| 2-May-2019 | risky    |     1 |
| 3-May-2019 | active   |     1 |
| 3-May-2019 | inactive |     0 |
| 3-May-2019 | risky    |     1 |
| 4-May-2019 | active   |     1 |
| 4-May-2019 | inactive |     0 |
| 4-May-2019 | risky    |     1 |
| 5-May-2019 | active   |     3 |
| 5-May-2019 | inactive |     0 |
| 5-May-2019 | risky    |     1 |
| ...        | ...      |   ... |
+------------+----------+-------+
```

**Fiddle:**

```
--create date table (not sure if usable)
CREATE TABLE #dates ([date] date)
DECLARE @dIncr DATE = '2019-05-01'
DECLARE @dEnd DATE = dateadd(day,-1,getdate())
WHILE (@dIncr <= @dEnd)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO #dates ([date]) VALUES (@dIncr)
  SELECT @dIncr = DATEADD(day,1,@dIncr)
END
GO

-- ID + Subscribed Date (starts active at joindate)
create table #t1 (id int, [subdate] date)
insert into #t1 values 
(9, '2019-01-01'),
(1, '2019-05-02'),
(2, '2019-05-05'),
(3, '2019-05-05'),
(4, '2019-05-10')
GO

-- ID + Latest activity date
create table #t2 (id int, [status] varchar(max), [datestatus] date)
insert into #t2 values 
(9,'risky', '2019-03-01'),
(1, 'active', '2019-05-02'),
(2, 'inactive', '2019-05-13'),
(3, 'active', '2019-05-14'),
(4, 'risky', '2019-05-15')
GO

-- ID + Activity Logs Date
create table #t3 (id int, [statuschange] varchar(max), [datechange] date)
insert into #t3 values 
(9,'inactive', '2019-01-01'),
(9,'active', '2019-02-01'),
(9,'risky', '2019-03-01'),
(2, 'risky', '2019-05-08'),
(2, 'inactive', '2019-05-13'),
(3, 'inactive', '2019-05-08'),
(3, 'active', '2019-05-14'),
(4, 'inactive', '2019-05-15'),
(4, 'risky', '2019-05-15')
GO
```

**What I have for now:**

```
;with cte as (
    select 
        #t1.id
        ,COALESCE(LAG(datechange) over(partition by #t1.id order by datechange),subdate) as StartDate
        ,#t3.datechange
        ,COALESCE(LAG(statuschange) over(partition by #t1.id order by datechange),'active') as PreviousStatusChange
        ,#t3.statuschange
    from #t1
    inner join #t2 on #t1.id=#t2.id
    left join #t3 on #t1.id=#t3.id
) 

        select 
            cte.id
            ,cte.StartDate
            ,coalesce(cte.datechange,'2099-01-01') as EndDate
            ,PreviousStatusChange
            ,coalesce(statuschange,previousstatuschange) AS NewStatus
        from cte
```

Comment: Use a Calendar and Tally Table.

Comment: @Larnu I have it in my fiddle. But its the logic of forcing the count for each day if there are no values that i cant figure out how

Comment: You need to use a calendar table with every date in it or a tally table. The root of the issue is your base table in the query needs to have every day in it. Then you join the every day table to your data so you can get a row when the count is zero.

Comment: @Larnu i don't see how this question is a duplicate? I know a date table needs to be used. the issue here is taking the status change  into consideration .

Comment: Can you show us your attempt then please?

Comment: @Larnu i have very little for now just edited my question

Comment: does table 3 contain even initial status of an Id? I mean does it create an entry in table 3 as soon as an ID added to table1?

Comment: @UmairRamzan it should but the problem is that the actual table was imported with data starting jan 1st 2018 but there are ids who joined since 2014.

Comment: I've modified what I have for now. I've created interval dates. now i need to find a way to link it to each day.

Comment: Great job posting sample data, desired results and current attempt!

Comment: *"When there are more than one status change in one day, the most recent one is the one to choose."* But how can you tell which is the most recent? you don't have the time of day, just the date... In the sample data currently posted, the last two rows inserted into the `#t3` table are for the same id and on the same date. Unless you also keep the time of insertion or an identity column, you can't tell which record between these two is the first, since database tables are unsorted by nature.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes the real data in the db is datetime, for the simplicity of everything i kept date. maybe i should have kept datetime. but if there is a row_number of cross apply top 1 to extract the first date, just use which ever in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dates table is the right way to go for this. You need seed data to get your desired output. I opened up your dates table so the older subscriber would fill in.

I also added a status table because your output requirement needs one row for every date for each status.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #dates
CREATE TABLE #dates ([date] date)
DECLARE @dIncr DATE = '01/01/2019'
DECLARE @dEnd DATE = dateadd(day,-1,getdate())
WHILE (@dIncr <= @dEnd)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO #dates ([date]) VALUES (@dIncr)
  SELECT @dIncr = DATEADD(day,1,@dIncr)
END
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #status
CREATE TABLE #status (status varchar(20))
INSERT INTO #status VALUES
('active'),
('inactive'),
('risky')
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t1
create table #t1 (id int, [subdate] date)
insert into #t1 values 
(9, '2019-01-01'),
(1, '2019-05-02'),
(2, '2019-05-05'),
(3, '2019-05-05'),
(4, '2019-05-10')
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t2
create table #t2 (id int, [status] varchar(max), [datestatus] date)
insert into #t2 values 
(9,'risky', '2019-03-01'),
(1, 'active', '2019-05-02'),
(2, 'inactive', '2019-05-13'),
(3, 'active', '2019-05-14'),
(4, 'risky', '2019-05-15')
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t3
create table #t3 (id int, [statuschange] varchar(max), [datechange] date)
insert into #t3 values 
(9,'inactive', '2019-01-01'),
(9,'active', '2019-02-01'),
(9,'risky', '2019-03-01'),
(2, 'risky', '2019-05-08'),
(2, 'inactive', '2019-05-13'),
(3, 'inactive', '2019-05-08'),
(3, 'active', '2019-05-14'),
(4, 'inactive', '2019-05-15'),
(4, 'risky', '2019-05-15')
GO

DECLARE
    @From DATE
    , @Thru DATE;

SET @From = '05/01/2019';
SET @Thru = '05/19/2019';

WITH
output_foundation AS
(
    SELECT date, status
    FROM #dates CROSS JOIN #status
)
, id_foundation AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT id, date
    FROM #t1 CROSS JOIN #Dates
)
, id_stat AS
(
    SELECT id, datechange, statuschange FROM #t3
    UNION
    SELECT id, subdate, 'active' FROM #t1
    UNION
    SELECT id, datestatus, status FROM #t2
)
, id_spread AS
(
    SELECT
        IFDN.id
        , IFDN.date
        , IDS.statuschange
    FROM
        id_foundation AS IFDN
        LEFT OUTER JOIN id_stat AS IDS
            ON IFDN.id = IDS.id
                AND IFDN.date = IDS.datechange
), id_fill AS
(
    SELECT
        IDS.id
        , IDS.date
        , COALESCE(IDS.statuschange, LS.statuschange) AS statuschange
    FROM
        id_spread AS IDS
        OUTER APPLY
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 statuschange
            FROM id_spread
            WHERE id = IDS.id AND date < IDS.date AND statuschange IS NOT NULL
            ORDER BY date DESC
        ) AS LS
    WHERE
        (IDS.statuschange IS NOT NULL OR LS.statuschange IS NOT NULL)
)

SELECT
    OFDN.date
    , OFDN.status
    , COUNT(statuschange) AS count
FROM
    output_foundation AS OFDN
    LEFT OUTER JOIN id_fill AS IDF
        ON OFDN.date = IDF.date
            AND OFDN.status = IDF.statuschange
WHERE
    OFDN.date >= @From
    AND OFDN.date <= @Thru
GROUP BY
    OFDN.date
    , OFDN.status
ORDER BY
    OFDN.date
    , OFDN.status;
```

Comment: This looks great! You've omitted #t2 but it is a crucial component. In the actual db of #t3, data was only imported for the past year only. So if there were any status changes on a specific id before that, it'll be counted as active (according to your code). That's why #t2 exists, it allows to get the most recent status for ids that won't have status logs in #t3

Comment: Should i union to #t2 as well and replace UNION ALL to UNION?

Comment: @RogerSteinberg Updated answer. I omitted table 2 because table 3 already had the same data. Based on the scenario you just outlined you are correct. UNION table 2 in the id_stat CTE.

Answer (score 0):

Might be below query will help you. I am not sure like it is same result as you want because you mention desired output which not match with your sample data which you provided in temp table query.
Currently I am considering  like you need commutative sum of each status of every day till now.

```
SELECT 
R.date
,R.status
,SUM (StausValue) OVER (PARTITION BY [status] ORDER BY date) AS Count
FROM 
(
SELECT Q.* , CASE WHEN T3.datechange IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as StausValue FROM (
select D.Date, t2.[status] from #dates  D
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT [status] FROM #t2 )t2
)Q
LEFT JOIN #T3 T3 ON T3.[statuschange]=Q.status AND T3.[datechange]=Q.Date
)R order by Date asc, Status ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you need to add two more things to your solution:

1. A table that will contain all day, so called [Dimdate](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/). I will ease getting the final result.)
2. A table with a history of statuses per id ([slowly changing dimension type 2](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/10g/r2/owb/owb10gr2_gs/owb/lesson3/slowlychangingdimensions.htm))  i.e.:
   [image]

Below you can find an examplary solution. It's not an ideal one, but I wanted to give you a general idea how it can work. For examply I didn't resolve a case when one Id change a status two times in one day. Basically, I created a SC2 table for each ID, DimDate and joined them together

```
--initial insert for new subscribers (they begin as active)
drop table if exists #t4
create table #t4 (id int, [Status] varchar(20), OpenDate date, CloseDate date, IsCurrent int)
insert into #t4(id, [Status], OpenDate, CloseDate, IsCurrent)
select
     id
    ,'active'
    ,[subdate]
    ,'9999-12-31' --we don't know CloseDate for this version
    ,1
from #t1

declare @i date = '2019-01-01'
--filing versions till 2019-05-15
while @i < '2019-05-15'
begin

update t4
set t4.CloseDate = case when  t4.OpenDate = @i then @i else  dateadd(day,-1, @i) end--avoiding overlapping versions
    ,t4.IsCurrent = 0 -- there can only one version that is current
from #t4 as t4
join #t3 as t3
    on t3.id = t4.id
    and t4.IsCurrent = 1
where t3.[datechange] = @i
--inserting a new version
insert into #t4(id, [Status], OpenDate, CloseDate, IsCurrent)
select
     t3.id
    ,t3.statuschange
    ,t3.datechange
    ,'9999-12-31'
    ,1 --the newiest version
from #t3 as t3
where t3.[datechange] = @i

set @i = DATEADD(day, 1, @i)

end

--populating an examplary DimDate
drop table if exists #DimDate
create table #DimDate (
dat date,
dateFormatted as FORMAT(dat, 'dd-MMM-yyyy')
)

set @i = '2019-01-01'

while @i < '2019-06-01'
begin
    insert into #DimDate(dat)
    select @i

    set @i = DATEADD(day, 1, @i)
end

--final result
select
     d.dateFormatted
    ,v.statuses
    ,count(t4.Status) as [count]
from #DimDate as d
cross join (values ('inactive'), ('active'), ('risky')) as v(statuses)
left join #t4 as t4
    on v.statuses = t4.Status
    and d.dat between t4.OpenDate and t4.CloseDate
group by 
     d.dateFormatted
    ,v.statuses
    ,d.dat
order by d.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

I omitted this part "When there are more than one status change in one day, the most recent one is the one to choose." You will need to find a way to select the last status for one day, with your current design it's impossible, maybe if you add a time column or an incremental id on  #t3....
it's working for me..., please copy the entire code and try again.
[image]

```
--create date table (not sure if usable)
CREATE TABLE #dates ([date] date)
DECLARE @dIncr DATE = '2019-05-01'
DECLARE @dEnd DATE = dateadd(day,-1,getdate())
WHILE (@dIncr <= @dEnd)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO #dates ([date]) VALUES (@dIncr)
  SELECT @dIncr = DATEADD(day,1,@dIncr)
END
GO

-- ID + Subscribed Date (starts active at joindate)
create  table #t1 (id int, [subdate] date)
insert into #t1 values 
(9, '2019-01-01'),
(1, '2019-05-02'),
(2, '2019-05-05'),
(3, '2019-05-05'),
(4, '2019-05-10')
GO

-- ID + Latest activity date
/*create  table #t2 (id int, [status] int, [datestatus] date)
insert into #t2 values 
(9,'risky', '2019-03-01'),
(1, 1, '2019-05-02'),
(2, 'inactive', '2019-05-13'),
(3, 'active', '2019-05-14'),
(4, 'risky', '2019-05-15')
GO*/

-- ID + Activity Logs Date
create  table #t3 (id int, [statuschange] int, [datechange] date)
insert into #t3 values 
(9,2, '2019-01-01'),
(9,1, '2019-02-01'),
(9,3, '2019-03-01'),
(2, 3, '2019-05-08'),
(2, 2, '2019-05-13'),
(3, 2, '2019-05-08'),
(3, 1, '2019-05-14'),
(4, 2, '2019-05-15'),
(4, 3, '2019-05-15')
GO
---Status Table
create table #t4 (id int, [status] varchar(max))

insert into #t4 values 
(1, 'active'),
(2,'inactive'),
(3,'risky')




;WITH unionall AS--- join data from t1 and t3
(SELECT id 
,1 as [statuschange]--starts active at joindate
, [subdate] as datechange

FROM #t1
union ALL
SELECT id , [statuschange] , [datechange] 
FROM #t3
),
 userstatuslog as(
SELECT id, [statuschange],datechange as beginingdate
,COALESCE( DATEADD(DAY,-1, lead(datechange) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY [datechange])), getdate()) as enddate
from unionall 
)
,datestatus as(
SELECT  
id, statuschange,   beginingdate,   enddate,    [date]
,case WHEN [date]< beginingdate then 0 
WHEN [date]>=beginingdate AND [date]<=enddate then statuschange
END as newstatus
FROM userstatuslog CROSS JOIN #dates)
,crossjoin as (
SELECT [date],id
from #dates CROSS join #t4

)

,removenulls as (
SELECT *
FROM  datestatus
where newstatus is NOT NULL AND newstatus<>0

)

SELECT 
crossjoin.date,crossjoin.id, sum(case when newstatus is null then 0 else 1 end) 
 FROM crossjoin  left join datestatus on crossjoin.date=datestatus.date AND crossjoin.id=newstatus
GROUP BY crossjoin.date,crossjoin.id
ORDER BY crossjoin.date,crossjoin.id
```

Comment: Issue when running the code: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value, i think its in your unionall